# Append div with text inside it into a larger div

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm trying to make a small chat application (like in facebook). Now the problem is, I have somehow made it work, but the next message box doesn't append where I want it to be if there are more than 2 lines in previous chat message. They overlap. Now I thought appending one or more br tags after each div of message will solve this but it doesn't.

How to dynamically append div after div inside a larger div, making sure the div boxes inside it do not overlap and are at least 20px apart?

Comment: create a example snippet of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the following solve your problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var smallerDiv = "<div class='container'><div class='floatLeft'>Some message</div></div>";
  var smallerDivRight = "<div class='container'><div class='floatRight'>Some message</div></div>";
  var alignRight = 0;
  $('#addMore').click(function() {
    var elem = $('#largerDiv');
    if(alignRight == 0) {
      elem.append(smallerDiv);
    } else {
      elem.append(smallerDivRight);
    }
    elem.scrollTop(elem[0].scrollHeight);
    alignRight = (alignRight + 1)%2;
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.floatRight {
  float: right;
}

.floatLeft {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="largerDiv" class="largerDiv">
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="addMore" value="Add more">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes. How to make some divs with 'smallerDiv' class align to right?

Comment: @PeterKim: Well.. That would be solved by floats. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thankyou. The chat functions very well now.